# VBA Worksheet Automation Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code at the start of a routine:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).[b4]).Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).[b6]).Sheets(1)
Set ws3 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).[b8]).Sheets(1)

ws1.Move after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
ws2.Move after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
ws3.Move after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")

'// remove redundant data
With ws1
    With .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)  
    ...
```

Everything seems fine until the second `With` block, when I get an automation error:

> Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)':
>
> Automation Error

Each of the files are CSV files with a single sheet, If I look in the locals window as they are being set they show as `Worksheet/Sheet1` as I expect. Once I move the sheets to `ThisWorkbook` however, I notice that the type changes to `Worksheet/Worksheet` and I am no longer able to refer to `ws1`, `ws2` or `ws3` using the respective variables. The variables show as worksheet objects in the locals window and appear to be set to an object, but when I expand the variable's node it just states `<No Variables>`.

I haven't seen this behavior before in VBA so any explanations or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it something silly like ws1 not having focus?

Comment: @99moorem shouldn't make a difference as I'm referring to an object set in memory, but nevertheless still didn't work - It seems to be keeping the pointer to the object but not any of it's properties or methods. Very strange...

Comment: can you do .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).address in the immediate window after you get the error? e.g. can you reproduce it manually?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the immediate window works (with reference to the worksheet variables), not even `?ws1.Name` any attempt to access the variables properties or methods results in an automation error.

Comment: Save reference to your source workbook in a variable (ie. `wb` ) then reference that rather than relying on `ThisWorkbook` as working with multiple workbooks may change your current active/this workbook.

Comment: @Meehow I did previously have references set to each workbook and assigned the sheets from there which did work, however my understanding is that `ThisWorkbook` points to the workbook in which the code is actively running. In this case it works as the sheets do move to the correct workbook. Could it be that Excel closes the original workbook as there are no sheets left after being moved and so the pointer/handle becomes broken perhaps?

Comment: @MacroMan oh you may be right. For me, after I move the `ws1` to the current workbook and add a watch to the `ws1` variable the variable is null which would mean the reference is somehow getting lost. I think if you reassign the reference after moving ie. `set ws1 = thisworkbook.sheets(X)` that should work

Comment: Change ws1 nulls itself after you move the sheet to the new workbook. Think you would have to refer to the sheet in the new workbook

Comment: @Meehow Yes re-assigning does work - interestingly though checking the pointer with `?VarPtr(ws1)` in the immediate window produces the same result when `ws1` is first assigned, after it is moved, and also after it has been re-assigned!? I'm beginning to think that it is something to do with VBA using a full qualifying path including workbook to save the variable when it is initialised, and so this would break once the workbook has closed - however I can't find anything documented to prove or disprove this :/

Comment: the code you have used will link ws1 to that sheet on that workbook only

Comment: Indeed - but _why_ ... If this is the case, what is the point in `Set`ting the object in memory?

Comment: @MacroMan because the workbook containing `ws1` is being closed. Reference is just getting lost in this case and not reassigned with the new workbook. Should it be automatically reassigned? Probably yes but it's not working that way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you move a sheet from a 1 sheet workbook, it closes the workbook. would need to refer to the sheet in the current workbook not the one from the opened workbook. Code similar to below would work.

```
Sub tt()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).[b1]).Sheets(1)
ws1_Name = ws1.Name

ws1.Move after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'// remove redundant data
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws1_Name)
    With .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    End With
End With
End Sub
```

You could also reset ws1 to the correct sheet

```
Set ws1 = ThisWorkBook.Sheets(ws1_Name)
```

Comment: I'll vote up as this is the same conclusion that I have come to, however I'm still curious to know _why_ this is happening.

Comment: are you asking why the sheet is closing that ws1 is lossing its ref or why ws1 does not stay linked with the same sheet when you move it?

Comment: why it doesn't stay linked - If you `Set` an object, it should set a reference to that particular instance of that object. The sheet being moved from one workbook to the other doesn't change the _instance_ and so the variable should still remain functional.

Comment: Hmm I can only assume that this is something that excel does not excel at. The ws1 is set to that sheet in that workbook and apparently that is static e.g. it does not move the reference in ws1 with it. I wonder if behind the scenes of the .move it is really doing .copy-to new dest .delete-orignal